# Oracle VirtualBox - Hangs when installing a guest O/S

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

Work laptop.  Had OVB 5 working perfectly.

Rebuilt after hardware failure.

Installed OVB 6.0.8

My config:

```
+ enable I/O APIC
+ Hardware clock in UTC
+ Enable nested PAE/NX  
2 CPUs
Hyper-V
+ Enable VT-x/AMD-V
+ Enable Nested paging
```

I have tried installing all of these:

```
Import an exisitng OVA
linuxmint-19.1-xfce-32bit.iso
Core-current.iso
ubuntu-18.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso
linuxmint-19.1-cinnamon-32bit.iso
```

They all hang.  Only Core-current.iso made it to the live state after waiting 4 hours, but when I tried to permanently install it - it also hangs.

Here is my laptop config:

```
WindowsBuildLabEx                                       : 
17763.1.amd64fre.rs5_release.180914-1434
WindowsCurrentVersion                                   : 6.3
WindowsEditionId                                        : Enterprise
WindowsProductName                                      : Windows 10 
Enterprise
WindowsVersion                                          : 1809
OsForegroundApplicationBoost                            : Maximum
OsTotalVisibleMemorySize                                : 8261208
OsFreePhysicalMemory                                    : 3564040
OsTotalVirtualMemorySize                                : 11905864
OsFreeVirtualMemory                                     : 5553108
OsInUseVirtualMemory                                    : 6352756
OsMaxNumberOfProcesses                                  : 4294967295
OsMaxProcessMemorySize                                  : 137438953344
OsMuiLanguages                                          : {en-US}
OsNumberOfProcesses                                     : 221
OsArchitecture                                          : 64-bit
OsLanguage                                              : en-US
OsPrimary                                               : True
OsProductType                                           : WorkStation
HyperVisorPresent                                       : True
HyperVRequirementDataExecutionPreventionAvailable       : 
HyperVRequirementSecondLevelAddressTranslation          : 
HyperVRequirementVirtualizationFirmwareEnabled          : 
HyperVRequirementVMMonitorModeExtensions                :
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You'll want to disable Hyper-V.

Comment: @essjae  Do you mean change "HyperVisorPresent :True" to HyperVisorPresent                           : False"?  If so, how does one do that?  Thanks

Comment: You could uninstall through control panel, this is the easiest way.